# Using GenemuFormBundle in Symfony2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, symfony, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use que GenemuFormBundle in my Symfony2 app. I followed the steps in the link below:

http://symfohub.com/repo/GenemuFormBundle/documentation

After that, it seems that it's installed correctly. At the bottom of that website it says:

> You use GenemuFormBundle and you seen that it does not work! Maybe you have forgotten form_javascript or form_stylesheet.
>
> The principle is to separate the javascript, stylesheet and html. This allows better integration of web pages.
>
> View a template example form view:
>
> https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/template.md

I copied that code to the template that renders my form. Then I downloaded jquery, jquery-ui and jquery-tokeninput, both js and css files, since it looks like that they are the files required to implement the Select2 features, and I placed them into the respective folders, and loaded them right (at least Symfony2 didn't complained about not finding them).

I also put the following code in my entity, using the genemu_jqueryselect2_choice instead of the default one:

```
->add('listofitems', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_choice',
    array('choices' => array('item1' => 'item1',
                             'item2' => 'item2',
                             'item3' => 'item3'),
          'required'  => false ))
```

The form loads and works correctly, but I'm not getting a select box like these.

But instead I'm getting the old-fashioned select box. The autocomplete feature doesn't work either if I use the genemu_jqueryautocompleter_entity option. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you done the first step on [this page](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/select2/index.md) to enable it in your app configuration?

Comment: If you mean adding the code to app/config/config.yml,yes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have had the same problem.

With these steps it works:

make sure to include the select2 assets . Or put the select2.css and select2.js in your web folder.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/select2.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Furthermore you should add your Select2 example code in your form twig file like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#el4").val(["AL","AZ"]).select2();
    $("#el4").click(function() { $("#el4").select2(); });
    $("#wait_tags_destroy").click(function() { $("#wait_").select2("destroy"); });
});

</script>
```

At least change the #el4 in your section id name

Answer (score 4):

Also important to add [following](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/template.md) to your twig template:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ form_stylesheet(form) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ form_javascript(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to install [fanforfun/select2-bundle](https://github.com/fanforfun/select2-bundle) and then using Assetic functionality in your template do:

```twig
{% block stylesheets %}

    {{ parent() }}

    {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' output='resources/css/*.css' 'bundles/fanforfunselect2/select2.css' %}
        <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    {% endstylesheets %}

    {% if form is defined %}
        {{ form_stylesheet(form) }}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    {{ parent() }}

    {% javascripts output='resources/js/*.js' '@FanforfunSelect2Bundle/Resources/public/select2.js' %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

    {% if form is defined %}
        {{ form_javascript(form) }}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that just loading the css and the js script, as the previous answer says, and applying the style to all select boxes, it works:

```
<link href="{{ asset('select2/select2.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/select2.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").select2();
});
</script>
```